# Powershell Function Parameters for filtering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell

I am trying to write a function which pulls all my servers from sql database. It works correctly. I need to implement filtering for each columns so I can call the function with one or more filtering ..

for example if I need to pull all UAT server I should be able to write something like this and it should pull all UAT -

> Get-SHservers -Enviornment "uat"

or

> Get-Shservers -Enviornment "uat" -Application "App1"

or any combination of that

```
function Get-SHServers
{
    $connectionstring = (Get-SHJson "D:\config\configdb.json").value
    $server =  Get-SHSQLData $connectionstring -Query @"
    select 
        b.Name as ApplicationName, 
        a.Name as ServerName,   
        a.FQDN,
        c.Name ServerRole,
        e.Name as Enviornment,
        d.Name Domain,
        f.Name ServerRegion
    from 
            server a inner join Application b on a.ApplicationID = b.ID 
            left join ServerRole c on a.ServerRoleId = c.Id
            left join Domain d on a.DomainID = d.id
            left join Enviornment e on a.EnviornmentId = e.Id
            left join ServerRegion f on a.ServerRegionID = f.Id
        WHERE 1=1
    order by 1
    "@
    foreach($item in $server) {
        $output = [ordered] @{
                    ServerName = $item.ServerName
                    FQDN = $item.FQDN
                    ApplicationName = $item.ApplicationName
                    ServerRole = $item.ServerRole
                    Domain = $item.Domain
                    Enviornment = $item.Enviornment 
                    ServerRegion = $item.ServerRegion
        }
        $obj = new-object -TypeName PSObject -property $output
        $obj.psobject.TypeNames.Insert(0, "sh.config.server")
        write-output $obj
    }
    }
```

I prefer to infuse the filter in SQL for performance reason any help to implement this behavior? * Should I be passing 7 different parameters to the function and validate in an [if else] if one or more parameter is passed and construct SQL or there is an easier way in Powershell to do this  *

Also, here is the implementation of Get-SHSQLData

```
  [CmdletBinding()] param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Query,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$connectionstring
    )

    $Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
    $Command    = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand
    $Adapter    = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $DataSet    = New-Object System.Data.DataSet


    if ($Query.Trim() -eq '' -or $connectionstring.Trim() -eq ''){
        write-host 'Query and ConnectionString are Mandatory Parameter' -ForegroundColor Red;
        return;
    }
    #$connectionstring = "server=$servername;database=$DatabaseName;trusted_connection=true;pooling=false"
    $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionstring;
    $Connection.Open()
    $Command.Connection = $Connection
    $Command.CommandText = $Query
    $Adapter.SelectCommand = $Command
    $Adapter.Fill($DataSet) | out-NULL
    $Connection.Close()
    $Connection.Dispose()
    return $DataSet.Tables[0]
```

Comment: What is your question? Have you tried to implement a parameter and failed?

Comment: This read more like a question about T-SQL syntax for the WHERE clause than a PowerShell question

Comment: What is the `Get-SHSQLData` function implementation?  You could pass parameter values to that function for a parameterized query.

Comment: There's not really enough information to tell what's going on, but personally, I'd keep the results of the SQL query as a DataTable or DataSet and then use a DataView to filter it however you require.

Comment: As an aside, the SQL code will be more readable if you use meaningful correlation aliases. For example: server AS s; Application AS a; ServerRole AS sro; Domain AS d; Enviornment AS e; ServerRegion AS sre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes*, you should be passing 7 different parameters to the function but, *no*, there is not really an easier way to do it because it is so straightforward already. Here is a sample with your first two parameters:

```
function Get-Stuff
{
     param
     (
         [string]$AppName,
         [string]$ServerName
     )

     $whereClause = '1=1'
     if ($AppName) { $whereClause += " AND ApplicationName = '$AppName'"}
     if ($ServerName) { $whereClause += " AND ServerName = '$ServerName'"}
     Write-Host $whereClause    # this line is debug output only
}
```

And here are a few examples demonstrating its use:

```
PS> Get-Stuff
1=1

PS> Get-Stuff -AppName "my app"
1=1 AND ApplicationName = 'my app'

PS> Get-Stuff -Server 'localhost' -AppName 'big app'
1=1 AND ApplicationName = 'big app' AND ServerName = 'localhost'
```

(Footnote:
Take a look at [Invoke-SqlCmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720(v=sql.120).aspx), which should allow you to significantly reduce the size of your code.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Parameter Sets.  This way you can use `Get-SHservers -Set1` or `Get-SHservers -Set2`

```
Function SCCM-ScheduledReboot{
 [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true,DefaultParameterSetName="ViewOnly")]
Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ViewOnly")]
    [switch]$ViewOnly,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="CSV")]
    [switch]$CSV,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Create")]
    [switch]$Create,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Create")]
    [switch]$Email
)


    Switch($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName){
        "ViewOnly"{
        ViewOnly
        }
        "CSV"{
        CSV
        }
        "Create"{
        Create
        }
    }
}#end sccm-scheduledreboot function
```

Here I create the SCCM-ScheduledReboot function which includes three parameter sets.  The default is ViewOnly, when the function is run without a param, it will default to ViewOnly.

Next I could use `SCCM-ScheduledReboot -CSV` and the function will call the CSV function.

Optionally, your function could have a single param that is passed into a SQL query contained in a here-string.

```
Function SCCM-ScheduledReboot{
 Param(
    [Parameter()]
    [string]$ServerQuery
)

$Here-String-Query = @"
<< Your SQL query here, include $ServerQuery >>
"@

}#end sccm-scheduledreboot function
```